# Assistance with function not working

Tags: python, list, function, sum, return

The `show_list` function of my code does not work. I get a message stating that `'multiples'` is not defined but I have not been able to identify the problem. Can someone please review and advice as to what it is Im doing wrong.

```
def main():
    input1 = int(input("enter the low integer: "))
    input2 = int(input("enter the high integer: "))
    input3 = int(input("enter the integer for the multiples: "))

    show_multiples(input1, input2, input3)

    print ("List was created")


 def show_multiples(input1, input2, input3):

    num_range = range(input2, input1, -1)
    multiples = []

    for num in num_range:
        if num % input3 == 0:
            multiples.append(num)
            return multiples


    show_list(multiples)

def show_list(multiples):

    elem = len(multiples)
    average = sum(multiples) / elem
    num_range = range(input2, input1, -1)

    print ("the list has", elem, "elements.")

    for num in num_range:
        if num % input3 == 0:
        print (num, end=" ")

    print ("Average of multiples is  ", average)



main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mutliples` isn't defined in the global scope, only in the scope of show_multiples()

What you likely want to do is in the global scope, change

```
show_multiples(input1, input2, input3)
```

to

```
multiples = show_multiples(input1, input2, input3)
```

Answer (score 1):

You call `show_list(multiples)` before you define the function  `show_list`

Put your main function at the end of your code and call main() to run it:

```
def main():

    input1 = int(input("enter the low integer: "))
    input2 = int(input("enter the high integer: "))
    input3 = int(input("enter the integer for the multiples: "))

    show_multiples(input1, input2, input3)

print ("List was created")
main()
```

To just call `show_list(multiples)` move it below where `show_list` is defined

You will have more problems though:

```
def show_list(multiples):
    elem = len(multiples)
    average = elem / sum(multiples)
    print ("the list has", elem, "elements.")
    # num_range not defined only exists in show_multiples and input3 is also not accessable
    for num in num_range:
        if num % input3 == 0: 
            multiples.append(num)
            print (num)
```

Not entirely sure what you want but I imagine this will get you closer:

```
input1 = int(input("enter the low integer: "))
input2 = int(input("enter the high integer: "))
input3 = int(input("enter the integer for the multiples: "))
num_range = range(input2, input1, -1)

def show_multiples():
    multiples = []
    for num in num_range:
        if num % input3 == 0:
            multiples.append(num)
    return multiples

def show_list():
    multiples = show_multiples()
    elem = len(multiples)
    average = elem / sum(multiples)
    print ("the list has", elem, "elements.")
    for num in num_range:
        if num % input3 == 0:
            multiples.append(num)
        print (num)

show_list()
```